# ¿Por qué repaint en java no me deja dibujar mas gráficos en el mismo componente?

Tags: java, java-swing

Bueno estoy haciendo un proyecto en java con netbeans, el proyecto consiste en que tenga 3 **radioButtons(cuadrado, circulo, ambos)**, sí el *radioButton "cuadrado"* esta seleccionado se dibuja un cuadrado de color en un **jPanel** y sí el mouse esta situado dentro de ese jPanel donde se dibujo el cuadrado, este seguirá al mouse.

Bien, ya logré que se dibuje el cuadrado y que este siga el mouse, además si el mouse ya no está situado en el panel el cuadrado se queda estancado en los bordes del panel, como sí fueran sus límites para moverse.

El problema está en que el método **repaint()** del panel, supuestamente lo que hice es que sí mueve el mouse el panel se repintará de blanco para dejarlo vacio y automaticamente dibujará el cuadrado en la posición del mouse dentro del panel, me limpia todo el panel pero no se queda el cuadrado dibujado sino que el panel queda en blanco, solo si sigo moviendo el mouse aparece el cuadrado pero parpadeando.

Sí quito el repaint sí se queda el cuadrado pero va pintado el panel del color y se va perdiendo la forma del cuadrado.

El código es el siguiente así tal cual esta en mi netbeans:

```
package interfaz;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

final private Graphics dibujo;
private int x, y, mouseX, mouseY;

public Main() {
    initComponents();
    dibujo = Panel.getGraphics();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public void addEventos(){
Panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evento){
        Panel.repaint();
        coordenadasLabel.setText(String.format("Coordenadas: [%d, %d]",
        evento.getX(),evento.getY()));
        mouseX = evento.getX();
        mouseY = evento.getY();
        if(cuadradoRButton.isSelected())
            dibujarCuadrado();
    }
});
}

void dibujarCuadrado()
{
    x = mouseX - 25;
    y = mouseY - 25;
    if(mouseX <= 25)
        x = 0;
    if(mouseY <= 25)
        y = 0;
    if(mouseX >= 505)
        x = 480;
    if(mouseY >= 355)
        y = 330;

    dibujo.setColor(Color.orange);
    dibujo.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    dibujo.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    Botones = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    cuadradoRButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    circuloRButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    ambosRButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    coordenadasLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    salirButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 52));
    setIconImage(getIconImage());
    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 485));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 485));
    setUndecorated(true);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    cuadradoRButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    Botones.add(cuadradoRButton);
    cuadradoRButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    cuadradoRButton.setText("Cuadrado");
    cuadradoRButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cuadradoRButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(cuadradoRButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 30, -1, -1));

    circuloRButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    Botones.add(circuloRButton);
    circuloRButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    circuloRButton.setText("Circulo");
    circuloRButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            circuloRButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(circuloRButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(220, 30, -1, -1));

    ambosRButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    Botones.add(ambosRButton);
    ambosRButton.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    ambosRButton.setText("Ambos");
    getContentPane().add(ambosRButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 30, -1, -1));

    Panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    Panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Plano"));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout PanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Panel);
    Panel.setLayout(PanelLayout);
    PanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 520, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    PanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        PanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 357, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    getContentPane().add(Panel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 70, 530, 380));

    coordenadasLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    getContentPane().add(coordenadasLabel, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 460, -1, -1));

    salirButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/salir.png"))); // NOI18N
    salirButton.setBorder(null);
    salirButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    salirButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    salirButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            salirButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(salirButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(500, 20, -1, -1));

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
    jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(556, 495));
    jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 495));
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(556, 495));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 550, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 495, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 550, 485));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void salirButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    System.exit(0);
}                                           

private void cuadradoRButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
   addEventos();
}                                                                                             

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Main().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public static javax.swing.ButtonGroup Botones;
private javax.swing.JPanel Panel;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton ambosRButton;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton circuloRButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel coordenadasLabel;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton cuadradoRButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JButton salirButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

***¿Cuál es el problema con el repaint del panel? ¿Por qué no se queda el cuadrado dibujado sí el lo último que hago cuando se mueve el mouse?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola Josué!
Existen otras técnicas para dibujar algún gráfico sobre un **jPanel**, te recomiendo que leas un poco más, en internet encuentras mucha información sobre esto ([pintar sobre un jpanel](https://www.google.com/search?q=pintar+sobre+un+jpanel&oq=pintar+sobre+un+jpanel&aqs=chrome..69i57.2675j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).
Además que usar el diseñador gráfico es algo incómodo, especialmente cuando tratas de modificar algún método, sin embargo, es posible.
Lo más interesante del diseñador gráfico de Netbeans es que te deja utilizar tus propias clases personalizadas y si esta es heredada de un **componente Swing** (como es el caso del **jPanel**), basta con arrastrarlo hasta el espacio de trabajo.

Sin más preámbulo, decidí probar tu código y lo modifiqué de la manera en que pensé que sería *"más sencillo"* (aclaro que esta **NO** es la forma en que yo lo haría, sin embargo, para ajustarlo a tu código, modifiqué algunas cosas manteniendo la misma secuencia que llevabas).

Adjuntaré los métodos que modifiqué, los que no veas es porque no los toqué:

Las variables quedaron así:

```
//final private Graphics dibujo; < No hace falta crear un objeto de Gráficos
private int x, y, mouseX, mouseY;
```

El constructor quedó así:

```
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    //dibujo = Panel.getGraphics(); < esto tampoco hará falta
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Esta opción la encuentras en la pestaña "Code > Generate Center" del Frame
}
```

Esa opción la ves acá:

[image: img1]

El método *addEventos()* quedó así:

```
public void addEventos() {
    Panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evento) {
            mouseX = evento.getX(); // Almacena la posición X del mouse
            mouseY = evento.getY(); // Almacena la posición Y del mouse
        }
    });
}
```

Aproveché las dos variables enteras que tenías para almacenar la posición del ratón, lo demás lo eliminé de acá.

El método *dibujarCuadrado()* quedó así:

```
void dibujarCuadrado(Graphics g) {
    x = mouseX - 25;
    y = mouseY - 25;
    if (mouseX <= 25) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if (mouseY <= 25) {
        y = 0;
    }
    if (mouseX >= 505) {
        x = 480;
    }
    if (mouseY >= 355) {
        y = 330;
    }

    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    //g.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50); < No creo que sea necesario, basta con el fillRect
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

Ya que el borde que dibujabas con el método *drawRect(...)* era cubierto por el siguiente método *fillRect(...)*, pensé que no era necesario.

Y por último, el **jPanel**:

```
Panel = new javax.swing.JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        coordenadasLabel.setText(String.format("Coordenadas: [%d, %d]",
                mouseX, mouseY)); // < acá simplemente se obtiene la posición de X e Y del mouse

        if (cuadradoRButton.isSelected()) {
            dibujarCuadrado(g); // < Esto llama al método dibujarCuadrado() y le pasa la referencia a los gráficos del mismo jPanel
        }
        repaint();
    }
};
```

Acá está un poco confuso modificar el código generado por el diseñador gráfico de Netbeans, sin embargo, es posible. Para lograr modificar el código y que quede de esa manera, selecciona el jPanel donde estás dibujando los gráficos, le das clic derecho y en el menú contextual elige la opción "Customize Code...":

[image: img2]

Se abrirá una ventana donde puedes observar el código generado por Netbeans, acá te darás cuenta que no es posible modificar el código, para modificarlo, debes desplegar la lista de opciones que está en el lateral izquierdo y cambia "default code" por "custom creation":

[image: img3]

Ahora podrás modificar el código (realmente, no es *modificar*, pero sí puedes agregar más código a esa línea). Lo siguiente será agregar dos llaves al final de la línea donde se crea la instancia del **jPanel** y hacer un salto de línea:

[image: img4]

Por último, simplemente escribe el código (o pégalo) justo en el medio de las llaves (a veces suele desacomodarse):

[image: img5]

Y eso es todo, con eso habrás hecho un **override** al método *paintComponent()* del jPanel desde el diseñador gráfico de Netbeans.

Aclaro nuevamente, yo no lo haría de esta manera, ni tampoco te lo recomiendo, existen formas mejores, sin embargo, para evitar el coste del código, así te funcionará:

[image: gif]